# Keyboard keys not working in game engine

Tags: keyboard, games

I just recently installed Urho3D game engine on Raspberry Pi 3.
But the problem is that when I run each of the example games, the game opens and I see the scene, but the keyboard keys (or even the mouse clicks) don't work, and I'm not able to move or do anything.
All I can do is Ctrl+C to quit (which sometimes doesn't work either!!).

How can I solve this !!?

Answer (score 2):

The fact that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> terminates the program suggests that its windows doesn't get the focus, so the keystrokes are passed to the terminal used to start it. You could try pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> (or whatever your desktop manager uses) to switch focus to the program manually, then try using the keyboard again.

Otherwise I'd suggest filing a bugreport to the developers. It looks like a project that might consider RPi users to be in his target audience.

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry-Grigoryev for your answer. But pressing Alt+Tab doesn't help.

Comment: @Omid1989 Does `Alt`+`Tab` work at all? I.e. is it the right combination to switch focus between windows?